# Wrong cross-reference to the bibliography in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

When I click on the section "Bibliography" in the Table of Contents, instead of Latex redirects to the bibliography section on the pdf file, it redirects to the above section, "Conclusion". Does anyone know how to solve it?

There is no error message or warning! It simply references wrongly. I use this to add the bibliography in Table of Contents:

```
\begin{document}
\arial
\nocite{*}                
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliography{References}
\normalfont
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  You need to share a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem if you want to get much help here.  We're all just guessing otherwise...  (but my guess is that if you recompile again the problem will go away).

Comment: When I click on the section "Bibliography", instead of redirects to the bibliography section on the pdf, it redirects to the above section, "Conclusion"

Comment: yes I got that, but no one here can see your source code so none of us can help unless you can create an example that shows the problem and add it to your question so that we can see what might be wrong.

Comment: Try adding  `\clearpage\phantomsection` before the `\addcontentsline{...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\bibliography` usually sets a starred chapter `\chapter*` and these do not end up in the ToC by default. The following example (with or without [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) highlights this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  date         = 1961,
  volume       = 22,
  pages        = {579-588},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular chapter}

\chapter*{Starred chapter}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Only `\chapter{Regular chapter}` makes its way into the ToC. The most straight-forward way around this is to insert the `\chapter*` into the ToC *manually*. This can be achieved using

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection% If you're using hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
```

- `\cleardoublepage` defaults to `\clearpage` under `oneside`, so might be safer to use in general.
- `\phantomsection` (if you're using `hyperref`) will set a hyper target for whatever references might follow afterward. In this case it'll be your `\addcontentsline` entry.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  date         = 1961,
  volume       = 22,
  pages        = {579-588},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular chapter}

\chapter*{Starred chapter}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection% If you're using hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't the bibtocind (or what it is called), do this automatically?

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! The weirdest thing is that I have tried that in a very similar way but not using \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} instead of \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}.

Comment: @daleif: Perhaps. I've never had a need to use that package.